# I can't stop ProgressDialog with method dismiss();

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I don't know why my code not working. I read a lot of same problems, but this is in most cases right solution, but for me is not working. My AsyncTask looks like this:

```
public class SavingAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private static final String TAG = "DrawView";
private ProgressDialog pd;
private Context context;
private File saveFile;
private Bitmap bitmap;

public SavingAsync(Context c, File sF, Bitmap b) {
    context = c;
    saveFile = sF;
    bitmap = b;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    pd.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Saving...");
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    OutputStream stream;
    try {
        stream = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
        stream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Bitmap is saved sucessfully, but ProgressDialog run forever :/

Comment: check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are showing ProgressDiaog with

```
ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Saving...");
```

and show method returns a PreogressDialog object.

The dialog you are dismissing using `pd` reference variable using pd.`dismiss()` in your code does to have reference to dialog you are showing. You should assign it to `pd`. Like this

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Saving...");
```

And then calling `pd.dismiss()` will dismiss the currently showing `Dialog`.

Comment: Yes, don't worry...it works after 10 minutes from post question.